# Error message when running EfficientFrontier from pypfopt module

Tags: python, optimization

Getting error message: "SolverError: Problem could not be reduced to a QP, and no conic solvers exist among candidate solvers ({'qp_solvers': [], 'conic_solvers': []})" when running .min_volatility()

```
efficient_portfolio = EfficientFrontier(mean_returns, e_cov)
print(efficient_portfolio.min_volatility())
```

mean_returns is a pandas Series
e_cov is a pandas DataFrame

I'm new to coding and trying to build efficient portfolios using the pypfopt module.
Thank you